# DefaultTheme in Material-UI causes `Invalid module name in augmentation` error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

As described in the [migration docs](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#types-property-quot-palette-quot-quot-spacing-quot-does-not-exist-on-type-defaulttheme) (v4 to v5) I've added this to my theme:

```
import { createTheme, Theme } from '@mui/material/styles'
import { grey } from '@mui/material/colors'

declare module '@mui/styles/defaultTheme' { // <-- ts error
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface
  interface DefaultTheme extends Theme {}
}

const { palette } = createTheme()
const { augmentColor } = palette

// Create a theme instance.
export const theme: Theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    neutral: augmentColor({ color: { main: grey[400] } }),
  }
})
```

But I get the ts error `Invalid module name in augmentation, module '@mui/styles/defaultTheme' cannot be found.ts(2664)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As of October 2022, the doc no longer mentions about "declare module '@mui/styles/defaultTheme'". So, I think that the declaration isn't necessary anymore

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't know why, but importing the module for side-effects fix it:

```
import { Theme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import "@mui/styles";

declare module "@mui/styles/defaultTheme" {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface (remove this line if you don't have the rule enabled)
  interface DefaultTheme extends Theme {}
}
```

Comment: This fix worked for me too—something with the internals of TypeScript ambient module resolution I guess. Interestingly, I did not get this error running tsc in the root project—only when running it in a sub-project with its own tsconfig. Adding the top-level node_modules folder to `typeRoots` did not fix it.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work in react18 or higher. I recommend you migrate to Emotion instead of JSS as suggested by the docs here: https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/migrating-from-jss/

Comment: but... I'm already using emotion's `styled` and still getting the error migration docs saying me to fix... and also getting this other error. which is not fixed by this other fix

Comment: I just fixed it by manually specifying which `Theme` I'm using, like this `styled(ToggleButtonGroup)(({ theme }: { theme: Theme })` and importing `Theme` from `@mui/system` instead of the one `@emotion/styled` has